# how to send query string to another page without displaying question mark in url

Tags: php

how to send query string to another page without displaying question mark in url.
I want to send a value to another page when i click on a link but i don't want to show how to hide question mark from url.
I am using apache.
This is my url that contains ? mark
http://localhost/learnindia/sub-category.php?category=automobiles-and-riksha

and i want like this
http://localhost/learnindia/sub-category/automobiles-and-riksha

any one help me that have knowledge about url rewritting.

Comment: Use ajax call..

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SO.  The links you provided are to your own machine.

Comment: yes i am developing at my own machine

Comment: can you tell me which code i have to use for this case

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess for url rewritting

for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what webserver you're using. If it's Apache then, in the `root` directory (where your index.php reside), create `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sub-category/?$ sub-category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Make sure your apache does not prohibit the use of `.htaccess`. You can also modify apache configuration file directly, but I wouldn't recommend that. Simply use htaccess.

Comment: Hello sir thanks for sharing, I am using apache and i tried your code but the code is not work

Answer (score 0):

You can always post the data and hide it from the url

```
<?php
function send_via_post($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using POST method in your form

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">
```

You then retrieve it using

```
$var = $_POST['name_of_field'];
```

PLease also make sure you sanitize your input as you can never trust user input!

This will not display the data in the URL but please be warned that any season professional can still see the data even via POST as the data is then sent with the body of the content.